# Creating existing application into mobile friendly app

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp

my application is currently running in java EE 5 struts 1.2 using ajax. and in front end its using html 4 and jsp.
i am converting the UI with angular JS and bootstrap . what are the changes required to be made at backend or more technologies required to be used to make proper changes in my app ?

Answer (score 0):

> what are the changes required to be made at backend or more
>   technologies required to be used to make proper changes in my app

As you told you are already using ajax and jquery. Assuming you must be returning response in json format. In best case scenarios, there can be no change at back end As angular JS is about front end and making your app toward single page app, unit testable, lesser coding, mvc oriented on client side where as Bootstrap helps you to go towards responsive designing where you application can fit all devices.